# Environment desktop doesn't load

Tags: 16.04

I upgraded from Ubuntu LTS 14.04 to LTS 16.04. I have a problem and it's that my computer doesn't charge any environment desktop (I've installed MATE, LXQt and KDE Plasma 5.7). It just shows "Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ubuntu tty1" and the option to log in. Any ideas?

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

## Graphics Drivers

I would say that your drivers for your graphics card were not properly installed. To fix this just login to the command line (without desktop environment) and do this:

If nvidia, choose a drivers from [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia) list and install it with `apt`:

First you must uninstall the old drivers that are not working:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

Otherwise use the open source Nouveau drivers that ubuntu provides, try reinstalling them:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

> You can find out which one to install by going to the nvidia drivers website and putting in your system and card information

If you have a radeon/AMD card then I would follow [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver)

> NOTE: Because you haven't posted any logs of your system I can't do any
>   debugging and this answer may not work.

## Other possible problems

- It could be as simple as switching to another terminal using `alt-<f7>`
- Grub might need to be reinstalled on your system: `grub-install /dev/sda`
- Try restarting the xserver `systemctl restart lightdm`

  > If none of this works your going to have to post the logs somehow or just post the error message.

Comment: Switch terminal doesn't work, it just shows a black screen. I reinstalled Grub, it says "Installation finished. No error reported" I reboot and the problem was still there. I tried restarting the xserver and that's the result: "Job for lightdm.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See 'systemctl status lightdm.service and 'journalctl -xe' for details".

Comment: I have nvidia. I tried what you told me and it shows me the message "You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these" and show me some packages with unmet dependencies.

Comment: Try reinstalling lightdm or just using the xserver-xorg-video-nouveau package